# How do I capture first tuesday in a month with zero padded in Unix

Tags: date, unix, awk, sed

@Unix

I am trying to capture first tuesday of every month into a variable and trying to pad Zero against it without luck.

Below is the piece of code I was trying:

```
cal | sed -e 's/ \([1-9]\) /0\1 /g' -e 's/ \([1-9]\)$/0\1/' | awk 'NR>2{Sfields=7-NF; if (Sfields == 0 ) {printf "%d\n",$3;exit}}'
```

Can someone help me what I am missing here?

Comment: maybe some input sample (in your environnment) and expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
# for monday calendar
cal -m1 | sed -n '1,2b;/^.\{3\} \{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,2\}\) .*/ {s//0\1/;s/.*\([0-9]\{2\}\)$/\1/p;q;}'
# for sunday calendar
cal -s1 01 01 2015 | sed -n '1,2b;/^.\{6\} \{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,2\}\) .*/ {s//0\1/;s/.*\([0-9]\{2\}\)$/\1/p;q;}'
```

- `cal` option depend on system (tested here on Red Hat 6.6) and mean `-m` for monday as first day and `-s`for sunday (the attached `1` is for 1 month display). Take the line according to your specified output of `cal`.
- don't print line by default
- don't care of line 1 and 2
- take line with non empty second(/third) group
- take second(/third) group (position) of number until next one and replace by a `0`, remove trailng char
- take the 2 last digit of first group, remove the rest and print it
- quit (no other line)

thanks to @Jotne for all remark about first wanted day in second week (4th line and not 3th) and first day of the week

Comment: Does not work, try `cal -m 1 | sed -n '3 {s/ *[0-9]* */0/;s/[0-9]*\([0-9]\{2\}\) .*/\1/p;}'` should give `06` but gives `02`.  EDIT, gives `02` for any month.

Comment: Still wrong.  First Tuesday in January is `06` not `05` as output of your line now gives.  I do always post output of my command if its not to long. Easy to see if its correct or not.

Comment: strange, test here (Linux) for ` cal -m1 01 01 2015 | sed -n ...` return `06`

Comment: Ahh, you are on an a version that supports setting the day of week with `-m1`.  This does not work on `Ubuntu` and there `sunday` is hardcoded as first day of week.  What system are you on? Can you test it on another system too?  In Ubuntu `cal -m1` gives `January` (month 1) that is why I did not see the pitfall before.  This `cal -m1 01 01 2015` gives error on Ubuntu.  Change your command to work without `-m1` option and it should work on most system.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
cal | awk 'NR>2 && NF>4 {printf "%02d\n",$(NF-4);exit}'
03
```

To confirm its working:

```
for i in {1..12}; do cal -m $i | awk 'NR>2 && NF>4 {printf "%02d\n",$(NF-4);exit}' ; done
06
03
03
07
05
02
07
04
01
06
03
01
```

Or you can use `ncal`

```
ncal | awk '/Tu/ {printf "%02d\n",$2}'
03
```

---

If you like a version where you can specify name of week,
and would work if `Monday` is first day of week, then this `gnu awk` should do:

```
cal | awk 'NR==2 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sub(/ /,"",$i);a[$i]=i}} NR>2 {if ($a["Tu"]~/[0-9]/) {printf "%02d\n",$a["Tu"];exit}}' FIELDWIDTHS="3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3"
03
```

It uses `FIELDWITH` to make sure empty columns in start of month does not changes the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer.

```
cal | awk 'NR>2{Sfields=7-NF; if (Sfields == 0 ) {printf "%02d\n",$3;exit}}'
```

Above statement would do.`"%02d"` does it for me

Comment: This fail for all months where first Tuesday is first or second in the month.  Look at `cal -m6`.  Your solution gives `09`, correct is `02`

Answer (score 0):

bash and date. May be slower than parsing cal:

```
y=2015
for m in {1..12}; do
    for d in {01..07}; do
        if [[ $(date -d "$y-$m-$d" +%w) -eq 2 ]]; then
            echo $d
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Translating into awk: will be faster as it doesn't have to call date multiple times:

```
gawk -v y=2015 '
    BEGIN {
        for (m=1; m<=12; m++) {
            for (d=1; d<=7; d++) {
                t = mktime( y " " m " " d " 12 0 0" )
                if (strftime("%w", t) == 2) {
                    printf "%02d\n", d
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
'
```